# How can I indirectly call a macro in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
{% macro obj_type_1 %}
stuff
{% endmacro %}
{% macro obj_type_2 %}
stuff
{% endmacro %}

{{ (obj|get_type)(obj) }}
```

In this example, `get_type` is a filter that would return `obj_type_1` or `obj_type_2` -- ie, the name of the macro to call for `obj`. I don't want to mark up `obj` with configuration output because right now `obj` is used in several templates as structural data, to be rendered with different markup depending on the context.

I know the syntax here is a bit tortured, but I think that's because what I want to do isn't immediately possible in Jinja templates. I'm trying to replace a big damn schwack of if/elif/else crap in some config generation code with templates, but this bit seems to be a sticking point.

Comment: So you're basically looking for a way to `eval()` in Jinja2?

Comment: Close to; I want to call a macro by name.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a Jinja2 filter which gets the Macro from the current context and then evaluates the Macro.  The filter is:

```
@contextfilter
def call_macro_by_name(context, macro_name, *args, **kwargs):
    return context.vars[macro_name](*args, **kwargs)
```

If your application requires, you can perform string manipulation on macro_name before looking up the Macro in context.vars.

Here is a full example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from jinja2 import Environment, contextfilter

@contextfilter
def call_macro_by_name(context, macro_name, *args, **kwargs):
    return context.vars[macro_name](*args, **kwargs)

template_string = """\
{%- macro MyMacro(item) %}MyMacro({{ item }}){% endmacro -%}
{{ MyMacro('direct') }}
{{ 'MyMacro' | macro('indirect') }}
"""

env = Environment()
env.filters['macro'] = call_macro_by_name
template = env.from_string(template_string)
print(template.render())
```

which prints

```
MyMacro(direct)
MyMacro(indirect)
```

Answer (score 6):

Macros can simply called by import dict usage:

**macros.html**

```
{% macro render_foo(value) %}
HELLO {{ value }}!
{% endmacro %}
```

**my_view.html**

```
{% import "macros.html" as my_macros %}

{% set macro_name = 'render_' + dynamic_content %}
{{ my_macros[macro_name]('world') }}
```

render as:

```
HELLO world!
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, since get_type is used as a dispatcher, it would be more transparent to implement it as a jinja macro that calls a specialized macro based on the type of obj.  This removes the need for it to return a callable macro and, at the same time, consolidates the specialized macros and the logic that dictates how/when they are used.