# Do Swig's macros support calling nested macros, dynamically?

Tags: macros, swig-template

I've created a Swig macro that dynamically calls new macros. The result I've found from doing this is that the HTML markup from within the nested macro is not rendering as HTML, rather it's rendering as an HTML text node which includes the HTML tag I used. My test markup was simply an H1 element with "Hello World!" inside the element.

Do Swig's macros support calling nested macros? Or any ideas of how I can get the HTML markup from the nested macro to render as HTML?

Here's the exact code I'm using for this test:

**macros.html**
Primary/parent macro (HTML renders fine):

```
{% macro call(macro) %}

    {% if (macro.name === "transitions") %}
        {% import "transitions.html" as transitions %}

        <h1>Transitions!</h1>
        {{ transitions[macro.method](macro.vars) }}

    {% elseif (macro.name === "grid") %}
        {% import "grids.html" as grids %}

        <h1>Grids!</h1>
        {{ grids[macro.method](macro.path, macro.vars) }}

    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

**transitions.html**
Nested/child macro (String is rendered):

```
{% macro slider(vars) %}
    <h1>Hello Slider!</h1>
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that didn't take long. Issue resolved!

**Solution** safe filter forces the input to not be auto-escaped:

```
{% macro call(macro) %}

    {% if (macro.name === "transitions") %}
        {% import "transitions.html" as transitions %}

        <h1>Transitions!</h1>
        {{ transitions[macro.method](macro.vars)|safe }}

    {% elseif (macro.name === "grid") %}
        {% import "grids.html" as grids %}

        <h1>Grids!</h1>
        {{ grids[macro.method](macro.path, macro.vars)|safe }}

    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Got the idea from this question: [jinja2: macro selecting macro or dynamic macro calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14016356/4029465).
Then looked up docs for "safe" on the Swig website http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#safe.

Exactly what I needed.

**EDIT:**

By the way, I also discovered that calling the nested macro in the normal way (macro.method) without using a dynamic key (macro[method]) worked without using the safe filter. Not what I needed for my specific situation, but just thought I'd throw that out there.